# Serial Read Data in TextBox

Tags: c#

On the click of Button i am giving my sensor a command(8Byte data) to send me data,
& i am reading data serially, My Sensor is transmitting(9-Bytes Data) & i have this serially available data read into string.

```
byte[] query = new byte[8] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0x0B };
    string incoming;

serialPort1.Write(query, 0, query.Length);
incoming = serialPort1.ReadLine();

textBox1.Text = incoming;
```

But Whenever i click the button my GUI get hanged i dont know what wrong am i doing, i have my serial port opened & closed properly, 
then why i am unable to display serial read data in Textbox

Comment: `ReadLine` won't return until the seriali port returns a newline. First *does* the sensor return newlines? If not, `ReadLine` can't be used. The data will have to be read byte-by-byte and inspected to see where a message ends.

Comment: Then what method should i use

Comment: Can you please suggest what method should i follow

Comment: How can anyone know how your sensor works? What does the sensor send? Bytes terminated by a special value? Or a fixed number of bytes? SerialPort has methods that can read one byte at a time or multiple bytes in a buffer.

Comment: what if i serial.readbyte method in for loop

Comment: Fixed number of Bytes 9 bytes

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like the sensor returns 9 bytes. The [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2) method that returns buffers is [SerialPort.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

```
var data=new byte[9];
var count=serialPort1.Read(byte,0,9);
```

If those bytes contain text, [Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___) will convert them to a string using the ASCII codepage.

That's a blocking method though. This means that the UI thread will block until the sensor returns data. This shouldn't be a problem in most cases. The serial port can be treated as a stream though through its [SerialPort.BaseStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. The property's type is `Stream` which offers async methods.

The following code won't block :

```
var data=new byte[9];
int count= await serialPort1.BaseStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 9);
```